# ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined in Next.js 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I got following erros in my next.js 13 project please help me to fix this problem.

```
[1] - error src\redux\store.js (12:15) @ localStorage
```

```
[1] - error ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
```

**this is how it looks in my terminal**

[image]

**this is my store.js file**

```
`import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import { rootReducer } from "./rootReducer";

const finalReducer = combineReducers({
  rootReducer,
});

const intialState = {
  rootReducer: {
    cartItems: localStorage.getItem("cartItems")
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems"))
      : [],
  },
};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  finalReducer,
  intialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default store;`
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Post text, not images of text.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just a hydration issue? Window.localstorage is a **browser** reserved variable but not so for server. Couldn't you just give a default value that both server and browser can consume and then once browser loads you update the variable? ( for example with a useEffect )

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Since `localStorage` is Browser API, it would need to run in the context of a browser. In Next.js, components are server components by default - so you would need to convert this to a client component.

Add `use client` directive at the top of the file and it should work.

Reference: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components